# Data Center in Terraform

Tags: terraform

So I'm really new to terraform and was looking up examples and documentations. I have a question about what this line means what its functionality is in the script, I'm seeing it in every data object in the script:

```
datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
```

Also, what does 'data' do in a line like this:

```
data "vsphere_datacenter" "dc" {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I think you  should at least start reading the excellent Terraform documentation and the vsphere provider **before** asking these types of questions.

Answer (score 0):

`data` refers to [Data Sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/data-sources/index.html) which:

> Data sources allow data to be fetched or computed for use elsewhere in Terraform configuration.

In your case, [vsphere_datacenter](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vsphere/latest/docs/data-sources/datacenter) data source is used which is used to **extract** the ID of an existing vSphere datacenter. Once the data source fetches this info from your existing infrastructure, it can be **referenced** in other parts of your TF script with `data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id`.